# Не работает Last(L) модификатор mod_rewrite

Tags: mod_rewrite

Доброго времени суток коллеги, собственно вопрос в следующем...

У меня прописано следующее правило:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [L]
```

Это правило делает переадресацию всех запросов на фронт контроллер... Тут никаких проблем нет и все чудесно работает. Проблема, почему-то, появилась  после попытки добавления специфических правил для папок css, js, img...

Собственно дописываю правило (естественно перед правилом для фронт контроллера)

```
RewriteRule ^img\/(.*)$ public/img/$1 [L]
```

Но все-равно запрос уходит на фронт контроллер... При этом если убрать правило для фронт контроллера - правило срабатывает так как и должно...
Еще что интересно... Если переписать правило для картинок как-то так:

```
RewriteRule ^img\/(.*)$ public/?lol=public/img/$1 [L]
```

То оно срабатывает и "главное" правило уже не отрабатывает, т.е. действительно приходит $_GET['lol']... Помогите пожалуйста разобраться в чем тут дело, а то у меня уже крыша едет не спеша...

Comment: DirectoryIndex и RewriteBase как прописаны?

Comment: DirectoryIndex  - никак не прописан, а при чем тут он вообще?<br>
RewriteBase - тоже не прописан, зачем его прописывать если / ставиться по дефолту?<br>
По поводу directoryIndex - в конифигах апача прописано только index.php (хотя причем тут это ума не приложу)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все гениальное просто.

```
RewriteRule ^(img|css|js)\/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*[^png|jpg|gif|css|js]$ public/index.php [L]
```

[[@shurik](/users/1182/shurik)](/users/1182/shurik) - а я не хочу указывать реальный путь и, в итоге, слава Богу этого добился :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы хотите для каждой css, иконки, картинки, js файла добавлять правило в .htaccess ??

Если нет, то используйте что-то вроде:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Или отдавать css и прочее вы тоже через скрипт хотите ?

**UPD**

скобки тут не причем.

`RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [L]`

это означает что **ЛЮБОЙ** запрос перенаправляеться на public/index.php

а теперь про Флаг L:

`Флаг [L] останавливает текущую итерацию обработки запроса. Однако если запрос был изменен теми RewriteRule, которые все-таки успели отработать, Apache запустит цикл обработки запроса заново с первого RewriteRule.`

т.е редирект идёт с / на /public/index.php

но проблема в том что /public/index.php тоже подпадает под маску .* и оно зацикливается. Вот, не поленился и выполнил сие. Лог:

`[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [error] [client 10.222.22.14] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [debug] core.c(3067): [client 10.222.22.14] r->uri = /web/fg.shurik.local/html/public/index.php
[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [debug] core.c(3073): [client 10.222.22.14] redirected from r->uri = /web/fg.shurik.local/html/public/index.php
[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [debug] core.c(3073): [client 10.222.22.14] redirected from r->uri = /web/fg.shurik.local/html/public/index.php
[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [debug] core.c(3073): [client 10.222.22.14] redirected from r->uri = /web/fg.shurik.local/html/public/index.php
[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [debug] core.c(3073): [client 10.222.22.14] redirected from r->uri = /web/fg.shurik.local/html/public/index.php
[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [debug] core.c(3073): [client 10.222.22.14] redirected from r->uri = /web/fg.shurik.local/html/public/index.php
[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [debug] core.c(3073): [client 10.222.22.14] redirected from r->uri = /web/fg.shurik.local/html/public/index.php
[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [debug] core.c(3073): [client 10.222.22.14] redirected from r->uri = /web/fg.shurik.local/html/public/index.php
[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [debug] core.c(3073): [client 10.222.22.14] redirected from r->uri = /web/fg.shurik.local/html/public/index.php
[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [debug] core.c(3073): [client 10.222.22.14] redirected from r->uri = /web/fg.shurik.local/html/public/index.php
[Mon Nov 14 17:20:49 2011] [debug] core.c(3073): [client 10.222.22.14] redirected from r->uri = /`

**UPD2**

Я предложил для статики указывать реальный физический путь, т.е /public/css/style.css .. и мод_реврайт отдаст нам этот файл минуя RewriteCond

Comment: И каким чудом сервер отдаст css, js или картинку?<br>
Зачем тут QSA? и при чем тут index?<br>
У меня L почемуто остальные правила не блочит, вы "немного" не о том пишите :)

Comment: гггг, всё с вами ясно. да, и почитайте внимательно про модификатор L ;)

+я немного удивляюсь, как это у вас подобное правило работает: RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [L]

Comment: А вы попробуйте и увидите что правило рабочее.<br>
Вы не подскажете отчего ему не работать? чем отличается .\* от (.\*) кроме того что при использовании (.\*) у нас будет это значение в $1?<br>
Все понятно с вами, вместо того чтобы помочь или промолчать написали не о чем... При это еще и "блеснули" про <b>.\*</b><br>
Я вкурсе что L не идеален и не дает гарантии того что больше не будет выполнено ни одного правила. Я прекрасно понимаю что можно написать "умные правила", но хотелось написать по простому...

Comment: Ну вот реально что нового вы мне написали? Ответили абыб ответить...

Comment: обновил ответ, в комент не поместилось.